# Are decompositions of products of Chebyshev polynomials (evaluated at a given point) into summands unique over extended integer rings?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, chebyshev-polynomials

The $i$-th Chebyshev polynomial of the 2nd kind is defined to be the polynomial $U_i(x)$ that satisfies
\begin{equation} U_i(\cos \theta) \sin\theta = \sin(i+1)\theta. \end{equation}

There exists an identity for the product of Chebyshev polynomials of the 2nd kind, which is as follows:
\begin{equation} U_i(x)U_j(x) = \sum_{k=0}^j U_{i-j+2k}(x) \qquad (i \geq j) \end{equation}
Thus every product of Chebyshev polynomials of the 2nd kind may be written as a sum of Chebyshev polynomials of the 2nd kind.

Now consider some fixed $n$ and consider the extended ring of integers
\begin{equation}
R=\mathbb{Z}\left[U_1\left(\cos\frac{\pi}{n}\right),\ldots,U_{m}\left(\cos\frac{\pi}{n}\right)\right],
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
m= \begin{cases}
\frac{n-3}{2} & n \text{ odd,} \\
\frac{n-2}{2} & n \text{ even}.
 \end{cases}
 \end{equation}

(The reasoning for this choice of $m$ is that the values of $U_i\left(\cos\frac{\pi}{n}\right)$ are symmetric either side of $U_m\left(\cos\frac{\pi}{n}\right)$)

My question is this: Is this 'decomposition' of a product of Chebyshev polynomials of the second kind into summands 'unique in the ring $R$'? To be more precise, given a product
\begin{equation} p=\prod_{k=1}^l U_{i_k}\left(\cos\frac{\pi}{n}\right) \in R \end{equation}
with each $i_k \in \{0,\ldots,m\}$, and given two elements
\begin{align}
r &= \sum_{i=0}^{m} a_i U_i\left(\cos\frac{\pi}{n}\right)\in R \\
s &= \sum_{i=0}^{m} b_i U_i\left(\cos\frac{\pi}{n}\right)\in R
\end{align}
such that $r=p=s$, do we necessarily have $a_i=b_i$ for all $0 \leq i \leq m$?

(Note that here we have $U_0(\cos\theta)=1$.)

Comment: Since the chebyshev polynomials are linearly independent (prove this), hence the decomposition of anything into summands of chebyshev is unique if it exists. Your work here shows that it exists (by induction on the number of terms).

Comment: @CalvinLin That is linear independence as elements of the ring of polynomials. You get uniqueness when you are decomposing a polynomial. Here they are expanding an evaluation at a specific point.

Comment: @CalvinLin Yes, Chebyshev polynomials are linearly independent over the ring of polynomials, though it is not clear to me that this is true for evaluations of Chebyshev polynomials at a point, such as with the ring $R$ I have defined above. As an example of how linear independence can fail for evaluations at a point one can note that $\left(U_1\left(\cos\frac{\pi}{5}\right)\right)^2=U_0\left(\cos\frac{\pi}{5}\right)+U_1\left(\cos\frac{\pi}{5}\right)=U_0\left(\cos\frac{\pi}{5}\right)+U_2\left(\cos\frac{\pi}{5}\right)$. This is the reasoning for the choice of $m$ in the definition of $R$.

Comment: I suppose if one can prove linear independence over the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(f)$ where $f$ is the minimal polynomial of $\cos\frac{\pi}{n}$, then the desired property I want should follow. However, that could be a tricky approach for arbitrary $n$. Unfortunately, it's been so long since I've done this kind of ring theory that I'm finding this a bit of a struggle!

Answer (score 1):

The answer, it seems, is no for general $n$. Here is a simple counterexample.

Consider the case where $n = 9$. With this choice of $n$, our ring $R$ is defined to be
\begin{equation*}
R=\mathbb{Z}\left[U_1\left(\cos\frac{\pi}{9}\right), U_2\left(\cos\frac{\pi}{9}\right), U_3\left(\cos\frac{\pi}{9}\right)\right]
\end{equation*}

Now one can use the identity
\begin{equation*}
2\cos\frac{\pi}{9}-2\cos\frac{2\pi}{9}+2\cos\frac{3\pi}{9}-2\cos\frac{4\pi}{9}=1
\end{equation*}
along with the fact that $2\cos\frac{3\pi}{9}=1$ to construct a polynomial
\begin{equation*}
x^3 - 3x - 1
\end{equation*}
whose roots are $2\cos\frac{\pi}{9}$, $-2\cos\frac{2\pi}{9}$ and $-2\cos\frac{4\pi}{9}$.

The first few Chebyshev polynomials of the second kind with respect to the variable $\frac{x}{2}$ are
\begin{equation*}
U_0\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) = 1,
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
U_1\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) = x,
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
U_2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) = x^2-1,
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
U_3\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) = x^3-2x.
\end{equation*}
Considering the quotient ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^3-3x-1)$ we obtain
\begin{equation*}
\left[U_3\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right] = [x+1]
\end{equation*}

Thus, we have
\begin{equation*}
U_3\left(\cos\frac{\pi}{9}\right) = U_0\left(\cos\frac{\pi}{9}\right) + U_1\left(\cos\frac{\pi}{9}\right)
\end{equation*}
and hence $U_3\left(\cos\frac{\pi}{9}\right)$ is linearly dependent in $R$.

I suspect that the original claim/question holds only if the degree of minimal polynomial of $\cos\frac{\pi}{n}$ is strictly greater than $m$.